# Heroku Schedule starts running function but then exits

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, hosting, scheduler

***Problem***

I have a node app deployed on Heroku and I'm trying to use Heroku Scheduler to execute tasks since node-cron doesn't work with Heroku.

The scheduler runs but it always exits with code 0.  A picture of the error message is below.

[image: Heroku Error Code]

I've been working on this for 4 hours already with no luck so if anyone has any suggestions that would be amazing!

***Code***

Here's the code in the file I'm using with Heroku Scheduler.  I have it scheduled to run every 10 minutes.  The getActiveComps function calls a function from another file in the node app that makes calls to an external API and then writes data to MongoDB via Mongoose.

```
#!/app/.heroku/node/bin/node
const getActiveComps = require('../api/functions/schedulerFunctions.js');
console.log('scheduler ran');


(async () => {
  console.log('before');
  await getActiveComps();
  console.log('after');
})();
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem! have you found a solution?

Comment: I haven’t found a solution yet djolf!  I set this problem aside a couple months ago but I actually need to solve it within the next month.  I’ll let you know what I find and if you can do the same that’d be great :)

Answer (score 0):

I never did solve the problem of running async function in a scheduled job, but I did a workaround. What I did was to make an internal API that ran the function, and make the scheduled job call the internal API to run the task. This may or may not work for you.

Defined a new API in my router:

```
router.get('/refresh', (req, res, next) => {
  //this is the function that I needed the scheduler to run.
  utils.getData().then(response => {
    res.status(200).json(response);
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: err
    });
  });
})
```

scheduled_job.js:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
async function run() {
  try {
    let res = await fetch(process.env.REFRESH_PATH);
    result = await res.json();
    console.log(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

run();
```

Of course, you should set your API path inside the heroku config vars.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That's a great work around!  I actually need to schedule my job more frequently than every 10 minutes so I'm going to try a custom clock process which Heroku also says in more reliable.  

My bandaid salutation for making it work in development was setting up a cronjob on cron-job.org to send an HTTPS request to my Heroku server to run my route

I'll let you know how the custom clock process goes, I haven't investigated if it works with async functions yet